# Trouble Compiling External '.c' Files: Word Search Program written in C

Tags: c

Hope everyone's doing well.

I was tasked with making a word search program, which I technically did succeed in doing.
Problem is, I was expected to use external files with these two functions:

```
extern int copyfile(char[], char *, int);
extern int output_array(int[], int);
```

I have the code already written and working inside the `main` function.

Initially having an external **copyfile.c** file with the below arguments and `while` loop:

```
    copyfile(filename, searchPatt, wordLen);
    while ((onebyte = fgetc(specialdata)) != EOF)
```

As well as an external **output_array.c** file with a `for` loop and these arguments:

```
    output_array(&i, found);
    for(i = 0; i < (strLen - wordLen); i++)
```

I thought would have done the trick but I've had no luck.

P.S. You will need to make your own sample text file to test **input.txt** with this program.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "copyfile.c"
#include "output_integers.c"

extern int copyfile(char *, char *, int);
extern int output_array(int[], int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    char *filename;
    filename = (char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); // Allocate space for the name of a file
    char *searchPatt;
    searchPatt = (char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); // Allocate space for the contents of a file

    printf("\nWelcome to 'Find Your Match' produced by Orange Blossom Lucky Software, Inc.\n");
    printf("Project leader: Nate");
    printf("\nThis program will find the matching strings in any file.\n");

    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the file to be searched: ");
    // Input ----------------------------------------------------------------

    scanf("%[^\n]", filename); // Read filename from user

    printf("Thank you. You entered ");
    printf("%s", filename);

    // Open File
    char *myfile = (char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); // Allocate space for file contents
    FILE *specialdata = fopen(filename, "r"); // Open file for read operations
    int j = 0;
    int onebyte; 

    copyfile(filename, searchPatt, wordLen);
    
    //printf("\n%s", myfile);

    int i;
    int found;
    int strLen;
    int wordLen;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter the search pattern you are seeking: ");
    // Input ----------------------------------------------------------------

    scanf("%s", searchPatt); // Read search pattern you are seeking

    printf("Thank you. You entered: ");
    printf("%s", searchPatt);
    printf(".\n");

    strLen  = strlen(myfile);  // Find length of string
    wordLen = strlen(searchPatt);

    printf("\nThe search has completed. The search key, ");
    printf("%s", searchPatt);
    printf(", is found in these positions within the file:\n");

    output_array(&i, found);

    fclose(specialdata);

    printf("\nThat completes the string search. Please enjoy your matches.");
    printf("\nA zero will be returned to the operating system.");
    printf("\nBye.");

    return 0;
}
```

**copyfile.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *myfile;
extern FILE *specialdata;
extern int onebyte;
extern int j;

int copyfile(char *filename, char *searchPatt, int wordLen) { // Definition of function

    // Reading -----------------------------------------------------------------

    while ((onebyte = fgetc(specialdata)) != EOF) { 
        //putchar(onebyte); // Just for us to see what's happening!
        myfile[j] = onebyte; // Copy the byte from the file into our array
        j++; // Update our 'j' counter
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

**output_array.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *myfile;
extern int strLen;
extern int wordLen;
extern char searchPatt;
extern int found;

//int output_array(int[], int); // Protoype

int output_array(int i[], int found) { // Definition

    for (i = 0; *i < (strLen - wordLen); i++) {
        // Match word at current position
        found = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < wordLen; k++) {
            // If word is not matched
            if (myfile[*i + k] != searchPatt[&k]) {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If word have been found then print found message
        if (found == 1) {
            printf("%d \n", *i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the **bash.sh** script I used to try compilation:

```
# First compile the c files into object files in any order, doesn't matter
gcc -m64 -c -std=c17 -o outputs.o output_integers.c
gcc -m64 -c -std=c17 -o copy.o copyfile.c
gcc search.c -m64 -std=c17 -c -o sea.o
#gcc -m64 -c -std=c17 -o sea.o search.c Line above is what the professor wrote, but I wonder if it should be this instead

# Now call the linker to link these object files into an executable file
gcc -m64 -std=c17 sea.o copy.o outputs.o -o search.out

# Now execute the executable
./search.out
echo Goodbyte
```

Here is the error the terminal gives me:

```
String_Search % ./r.sh
ld: library not found for -lmsea.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
./r.sh: line 16: ./search.out: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I've read the question, but I don't understand what it is you're stuck with. Something about `copyfile` and `output_array` being in an external (I assume this means different) source file? Are these functions provided, or are you being asked to write your code in a particular way? What are the functions supposed to do? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Your `myfile` string is not null-terminated.

Comment: Also, consider what will happen if the file contains more than 1000 bytes, as you allocated just 1000 bytes for `myfile`

Comment: @PaulHankin 
You understood correctly. Both `copyfile` and `output_array` are expected to be functions in external '.c' files. I assumed the "while" loop in the main function would go into the external `copyfile` function, and the "for" loop I thought would go into the `output_array` external function but when I tried to put them there I could not get the code to compile properly. I may also be writing the bash script incorrectly also, I will post that now.

Comment: @SGeorglades 
Can you explain why you said `myfile` should be null-terminated?

Comment: OK, but you've asked about one thing and posted code for another thing. Can you change the code in the question to the form that didn't compile, and show which code is in which files, and how you're compiling it, and what the specific error is?

Comment: @SGeorgiades is correct -- you're allocating memory with `malloc` which does not initialize to zero the memory it returns. A C string must have a terminating 0 byte, so your strings are quite likely not correctly terminated (so `strlen` and other C string functions have undefined behavior). You may well be unlucky though, and your code might appear to work correctly. As someone else correctly pointed out, your code won't work for files larger than 999 bytes.

Comment: @PaulHankin
The changes you asked for are live.

Comment: @SGeorglades
I'll be sure to correct the `malloc` issue now.

Comment: You shouldn't #include the c files -- the functions they contain will be linked together by the linker. But next, you need to try each line of the script in turn, and figure out which is causing the error. You might also `ls` the current directory, to see which files have been generated and which not.

Comment: Your `output_array` code is wrong. You initialize a pointer `i` to 0 and then dereference it `*i`.

Comment: There's lots of global state, and this makes your code inherently hard to understand (and almost certainly wrong). What are `output_array` and `copyfile` supposed to do? (ie: according to your professor)?

Comment: You'd be better discussing it and improving it with someone local to you. At the moment there's many things that are wrong with the code, especially the overall structure, that it's not a good stackoverflow question.

Comment: @PaulHankin
Alrighty, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not the script you used for linking. The script you used for linking has the broken option `-lmsea.o` somewhere, when it should have `-lm sea.o`.

Comment: `Here is the bash.sh` but you are runing `./r.sh` Please run `bash -x ./whatever_the_script.sh` and post the output.

Comment: I love your sense of humour: *Goodbyte!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in the code:

- extern definitions should be moved to a header file **search.h**, included by all .c files.
- C source files should not include other .c files
- global variables are error prone and in your case non existent, consider passing arguments instead of trying to refer to local variables in the `main` function.
- the bash script should be more consistent: object files should have the same basename as the corresponding source file and compiled with consistent compiler arguments. Consider using a **Makefile** instead of a bash script or at least echo the commands as they are executed.

Here are some proposals:

**Makefile**:

```Makefile
CFLAGS= -m64 -Wall -Werror

all: search.out
        ./search.out

search.out: output_array.o copyfile.o search.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ output_array.o copyfile.o search.o

%.o: %.c search.h Makefile
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

**search.h**:

```
extern char *copyfile(const char *filename);
extern int output_array(const char *myfile, const char *searchPatt);
```

**search.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "search.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filename[1000];
    char searchPatt[1000];

    printf("Welcome to 'Find Your Match' produced by Orange Blossom Lucky Software, Inc.\n");
    printf("Project leader: Nate\n");
    printf("This program will find the matching strings in any file.\n");

    printf("Please enter the name of the file to be searched: ");
    if (scanf("%999[^\n]", filename) != 1) { // Read filename from user
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nThank you. You entered %s\n", filename);

    // load the file
    char *myfile = copyfile(filename);
    if (myfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load file %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Please enter the search pattern you are seeking: ");
    if (scanf("%999s", searchPatt) != 1) { // Read search pattern you are seeking
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nThank you. You entered: %s.\n", searchPatt);

    printf("The search key, %s, is found in these positions within the file:\n", searchPatt);

    int matches = output_array(myfile, searchPatt);

    printf("Number of matches: %d\n", matches);
    free(myfile);

    printf("This completes the string search. Please enjoy your matches.\n");
    printf("A zero will be returned to the operating system.\n");
    printf("Bye.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**copyfile.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "search.h"

char *copyfile(const char *filename) {
    FILE *specialdata = fopen(filename, "r"); // Open file for read operations
    char *myfile;
    int size = 0;

    if (specialdata == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (fgetc(specialdata) != EOF) {
        size++;
    }
    myfile = malloc(size + 1); // Allocate space for file contents
    if (myfile != NULL) {
        rewind(specialdata);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myfile[i] = fgetc(specialdata);
        }
        myfile[size] = '\0';  // null terminate the string
    }
    fclose(specialdata);
    return myfile;
}
```

**output_array.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "search.h"

int output_array(const char *myfile, const char *searchPatt) { // Definition
    int strLen  = strlen(myfile);  // Find length of string
    int wordLen = strlen(searchPatt);
    int matches = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= strLen - wordLen; i++) {
        // Match word at current position
        int found = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < wordLen; k++) {
            // If word is not matched
            if (myfile[i + k] != searchPatt[k]) {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If word have been found then print found message
        if (found != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            matches++;
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Sample run:

```
charlie ~/dev/stackoverflow/search > make
gcc -m64 -Wall -Werror -o output_array.o -c output_array.c
gcc -m64 -Wall -Werror -o copyfile.o -c copyfile.c
gcc -m64 -Wall -Werror -o search.o -c search.c
gcc -m64 -Wall -Werror -o search.out output_array.o copyfile.o search.o
./search.out
Welcome to 'Find Your Match' produced by Orange Blossom Lucky Software, Inc.
Project leader: Nate
This program will find the matching strings in any file.
Please enter the name of the file to be searched: search.c

Thank you. You entered search.c
Please enter the search pattern you are seeking: int

Thank you. You entered: int.
The search key, int, is found in these positions within the file:
60
69
154
248
286
361
504
578
725
805
957
1031
1091
1184
1239
1306
1384
1450
Number of matches: 18
This completes the string search. Please enjoy your matches.
A zero will be returned to the operating system.
Bye.
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! My professor told the class he only want 4 files sent to him. He didn't tell us about using '.h' files with this project but the moment I created one, and the make file, it worked. You've been a great help.